# hibernate doesnt' save data to a local h2 database after the end of the app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

i have a class that saves and reads data from h2 database. If i use "mem" property it works fine. But if i use "file" property, after i stop the program, all data gets removed from db.
My hibernate cfg:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:d:\WebProjectDb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="com.webproject.Courses"/>



    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and this is my methods to read and save from db:
  SessionFactory sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

```
public void save(Courses user) {

Session session = sf.openSession();
session.save(user);
session.flush();
session.close();
}

public List<Courses> getCourses(){

Session session = sf.openSession();
List courses = session.createQuery("from Courses").list();
session.close();
return courses;
}
```

i would apreciate any help.

Comment: I don't see transactions in your code. In your save method, try `tx = session.beginTransaction()` and then `tx.commit()` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save()` method needs `transaction`, so you need to add it as shown in the below code with comments:

```
public void save(Courses user) {
     try {
       Session session = sf.openSession();
       Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();//start transaction
       session.save(user);
       session.flush();
       transaction.commit();//commit the transaction
    } catch(Exception exe) {
      ex.printStackTrace();  
      tx.rollback();  //rollback the transaction upon exception
    } finally {
       session.close();//close the session in finally always
    }
}
```